# Android Studio errors once detached from EXPO

Tags: android

I’ve been using Expo XDE and once I detach the project and run in Android Studio I'm having some major problems and can't sort it out.

Env Details:
Windows: 10
Android Studio: 3.1.4
Node.js: 8.11.3
NPM: 5.6.0
expo: 1.1.0-beta.5
exp: 57.0.0

Steps to replicate issue

Open upe Expo XDE and create new project
-> Run and test that it works in simulator in android studio (yes it works)

Open up app.json and add

```
“android”: {
“package”: “com.yourcompany.yourappname”
}
```

cmd line into project and ‘exp detach’

‘exp start’ (no errors given initially and gives url)

Open project in Android Studio (takes time with “Building ‘android’ Gradle project info”)

Build completes successfully with all oks.
Now in android studio I go to Run on the top menu, then select Run ‘app’

emulator screen goes white doesnt change and under the Run output I get these errors

(Also once all this was done I looked back in the cm line where I ran exp start and it now says “Metro Bundler failed to start. (code: EPERM)”)

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
W/AsyncCondition: Could not find listener for key: openOptimisticExperienceActivity
Could not find listener for key: openExperienceActivity
E/AppLoader: Error fetching cached manifest, falling back to default timeout: Could not load manifest. Are you sure this experience has been published?
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

              --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yourcompany.tes, PID: 7527
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yourcompany.tes/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)’ on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)’ on a null object reference
at host.exp.exponent.ExponentManifest.fetchCachedManifest(ExponentManifest.java:287)
at host.exp.exponent.AppLoader.start(AppLoader.java:91)
at host.exp.exponent.experience.DetachActivity.onCreate(DetachActivity.java:95)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7527 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```